# How to know the Rails environment in the react JS using webpacker gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, webpacker

What's the best way to access the `Rails.env` in javascript?

Currently I am using ReactJS with existing Rails project, using `webpacker` gem. (Not using `react-rails` gem)

> What I tried?

Set a javascript variable from the rails application (view template where my root component present) and access it in the root component JS. But this approach looks verbose to me as I needed to pass that variable all over the JS files in the react app.

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: I would more question why you have areas all over your react code that need to know which environment they are run in.  The number of things that change between environments should be extremely minimal and mostly limited to networking concerns.

Comment: Not exactly all over the app. So far I found few places, API module and one environment specific component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem. Gon allow you to push rails variables to global variables in js.

In controller:

```
     class SampleController
       def index
         gon.variable_name = variable_value
         ....
       end
```

and then you can access variable in js this way

```
      console.log(gon.variable_name)
```

Another (in my opinion better) solution is query for data you need to another rails action. In your react component you can use `componentDidMount` for this

```
componentDidMount(){
   fetch('http://url_to_fetch_data_from_server', {
     method: 'get',
     headers: {
       Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'X-CSRF-Token': 'token get from metatag',
  },
   credentials: 'same-origin',
}).then(response => {
     response.json().then(json =>{
       this.setState(yourData: json.yourData)
     })
  })
}
```

Then you can send data to all child component via props

Comment: worth to check `gon` gem. But I am not quite understand the second approach through

Comment: In your react component you can fetch data from server, save it into state, and then pass it into childs component